# Make @SerializedName in Java to work only when deserializing but not serializing

Tags: java, json

Is there some way to in the class, that a value will be obtained from `jsonField1` BUT when being sent out, it should be sent out as `jsonField2`.

```
Incoming json
{
    "name":"john",
    "gender":"female"
 }

Outgoing json
{
    "firstname":"john",
    "gender":"female"
}
```

The name of the database field is `firstname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about Gson here, but you didn't mention that.
Unless you want to write your own `TypeAdapter` you will need to use two different `Gson` instances, one for serializing and one for deserializing. 
For the one where the field name needs to differ you can register a `FieldNamingStrategy` using `GsonBuilder#setFieldNamingStrategy`. This interface allows you to remap field names.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it personally but this might work -

```
@JsonProperty(value="name",access=Access.READ_ONLY)
public void setName(String name){
  this.name = name;
}

@JsonProperty(value="firstname",access=Access.WRITE_ONLY)
public void getName(){
  return name;
}
```

If the above does not work, you could have two properties, incoming property annotated with `Access.READ_ONLY` and for outgoing have the property annotated with `Access.WRITE_ONLY`. However your BO or getter/setter need to deal with both the properties.